# Installed gems are not running

Tags: ruby, web, rubygems, jekyll

I am trying to install jekyll.
I run `gem install bundler jekyll`
After installing gems I run `bundle init` and get

> bash: bundle: command not found

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a gem's directory using `gem which`. For example:

```
$ gem which jekyll
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll.rb
```

Then append the directory to your PATH:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4:"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting "command not found" after installing gems is because they were installed in a location that your bash shell does not yet know about. The way the computer looks up commands is by looking at the `PATH`, which is a list of folders where the computer should look for commands, such as `bundle`. The previous answer is on the right track, but unfortunately, the `gem which` command will only tell you about locations that are already in your `PATH`, which might not include the folder where bundler and jekyll were installed.

The location of the gems depends on how you installed Ruby, so without knowing that, I can't tell you what to put in your `PATH`. What I can tell you is that what you are experiencing is unfortunately very common, but there is a fix. To avoid needless frustration and to help people like you, I wrote a script that will automatically set up a proper Ruby environment for you, including updating your `PATH` and everything else that is necessary to be able to install gems and use them right away without getting any errors. Check out the links at the bottom of this answer to learn more about my script.

In the meantime, I can make some guesses and see if I can help. If you installed Ruby with Homebrew, then this should fix it:

Run this command:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And then quit and restart your terminal. Now you should be able to run `bundle init`.

If you are reading this and you are not the original poster, you might need to replace `.bash_profile` in the command above with `.zshrc` depending on which shell you are using. You can tell by looking at the error. If you are using `zsh`, it will say `zsh: bundle: command not found`.

You can read more about my script and other ways to fix the "command not found" error in these articles:

https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/troubleshooting-command-not-found-in-the-terminal/
https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-jekyll-on-a-mac-the-easy-way/
https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/